# Javascript Intellisense in ASP.Net Usercontrols

Tags: javascript, asp.net, intellisense

As you will all probably be aware you can reference external Javascript files in Visual Studio 2010 using the following directive.

```
/// <reference path="MyExternalFile.js" />
```

Great!

Directives to external Javascript files that exist in masterpages are automatically transferred to content pages. Again great!

However how can you create a reference to a javascript file inside an ASP.Net usercontrol when the javascript file is declared in a masterpage?

I assume (although untested) that a scriptmanagerproxy would accomplish this. However I do not use a script manager in my web app.

Is there an alternative similar to what I display above for use in a UserControl?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit ugly but you could reference a JavaScript file just for the user control **without rendering** it:

```
<% if (false) { %>
<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

This way Visual Studio will give you Intellisense:

[image]

Comment: Looks beautiful to me. Thanks